# How to make do 'pixie-based' free drawing in fabricjs

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to make an 'Eraser' for my `fabricjs`-based 0.5 Opacity free drawing app(with non-trivial background image), i. e. everything drawing is half-transparent and we still can see the background through the free drawing.

However I understand by default all free drawing are 'path-based' i. e. everything we draw (between mouse-down mouse up) is captured as an individual path in the canvas, so it is not possible to erase arbitrary part of the path. So I am thinking maybe we can capture the mouse-down/up event manually and draw an image pixie by pixie and place it on the canvas with opacity=0.5? so that we can use white to overwrite all those 'old' drawing?

Is this a workable/efficient enough solution?

However I am not sure how this can be implemented in `fabricjs`? could you please give me some advise on the steps or some pseudocode? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't complete my attempt when i had a similar problem , but the basic concept was simple 'Read the pixel under the cursor(and under the canvas, where another canvas with a background image was) and paint the path with the same color' , creating an eraser effect. The starting stone was this jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/ maybe it can help you out, i didn't try it to its completion since the idea was quickly abandoned